# How to draw the highcharts by using the data got from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I want to draw a highcharts by using the value got from MySQL database. I get the value from database and encode into jason successfully, but the highcharts doesn't come up, can you help me?

====2016/10/05 update====

I add JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in my json_encode function to parse the strings into numeric type, but still can't show the highcharts correctly, can you help me?

====2016/10/06 update====

I upload the screenshot of my result here to show that I truely have the right json format of my data which got from my apache server. Left part is my code, the highlighted line 25 shows my result in right part of my screenshot. You can see the result I parse from database in json format is [3,2,6,9,5]. Why there is no highcharts below my webpage?

Screenshot here↓↓↓↓↓
[image]

**database↓**

```
CREATE TABLE `db` (
  `name` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `db` (`name`, `status`) VALUES
('dd', 'done'),
('ee', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('aa', 'done'),
('cc', 'done'),
('ee', 'done'),
('cc', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('cc', 'done'),
('ee', 'done'),
('bb', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('ee', 'done'),
('cc', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('dd', 'done'),
('ee', 'done'),
('cc', 'done'),
('cc', 'change'),
('aa', 'change'),
('aa', 'change'),
('dd', 'change'),
('bb', 'change'),
('dd', 'change');
```

**index.php↓**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2 align="center">INDEX</h2>



<form action="highcharts.php">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_schedule" value="View_highcharts">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**highcharts.php↓**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--invoke jquery first then highcharts libraries when you use highcharts to draw the plot.-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"> <!--put .js file in c:\xampp\htdocs-->
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h2 align="center">HighCharts.js demo</h2>

   <?php
    echo "JSON WORKS↓↓↓<br><br>";
    $sth = mysqli_query(new mysqli("localhost","root","","ask"), "select distinct name, count(status) as number from db group by name");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r['number'];
    }
    json_encode($rows);
    $rows_json = json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    print "this line is rows_json: $rows_json";
    echo "<br><br>JSON WORKS↑↑↑";
    ?>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**highcharts.js↓**

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('highcharts.php', function(data) {
            $("#container").highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'js_demo'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'number of count'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -30,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 25,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'done',
                data: data
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How your data looks like? Do you have correct Highcharts format?

Comment: After get from database and encode into json, it looks like: ["3","2","6","9","5"]

Comment: So you have strings instead of numbers? Maybe try to parse them to numbers?

Comment: Thanks for @GrzegorzBlachliński comment. After I add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` in `json_encode` function, the strings parse into numbers (it looks like [3,2,6,9,5]), but the highcharts still not work. Any other helps?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: No error occur. It just show a blank result

Comment: and your data is an array? And you can console.log this data in success function?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. Could you speak another way? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough. Is your data exactely in the format like [3,2,6,9,5] array? Are you sure that you are correctly getting your data from server?

Comment: I upload the screenshot of my webpage and the code, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of my question:

1. just REMOVE this line:

   $.getJSON('highcharts.php', function(data) {}
2. set the variable get from php, put it under `<head>` tag.
3. paste the js code under `<head>` tag instead of invoke highcharts.js into highcharts.php
4. echo the variable in the series object in js